# In java SE 7, whether all sub classes of runtimeexception and errors are unchecked exceptions?

Tags: java, java-7

As per java 7 version, I need to know all sub classes of `java.lang.RuntimeException` and `java.lang.Error` are of unchecked exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear about this (links are to Java 7, although of course the current version is Java 8):

[`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html):

> ..`Error` **and its subclasses** are regarded as unchecked exceptions for the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions.

*(my emphasis)*

[`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html):

> `RuntimeException` **and its subclasses** are *unchecked exceptions*.

*(my emphasis on the subclasses part, not the other part)*

This has been true for a **long** time, I think since 1.1 if not 1.0.